# error: storage size of ‘Img’ isn't known

Tags: c, size, storage, typedef, pgm

I'm trying to write a simple code to read in a .PGM file.  The code I wrote is

```
#include "./netpbm/lib/pgm.h"
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int gray;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    gray Maxval;
    gray* Img[];
    int row, col;

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("barcode.PGM", "r");

    pm_proginit(0, &argv[0]);

    &Img[0] = pgm_readpgm(fp, &col, &row, &Maxval);
}
```

it outputs error: storage size of 'Img' isn't known

any debugging suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, the size of `Img` isn't known... and that's that. Shouldn't be that hard to figure out...

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation of libpgm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/libpgm.html), it seems like you should declare a pointer-to-pointer:

```
gray **Img;
...
Img = pgm_readpgm(fp, &col, &row, &Maxval);
...
pgm_freearray(Img, row);
```

Comment: +1 - this answer is certainly the most correct.  That's what you get for reading the docs. =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give that array a size:

```
gray *Img[100];
```

Since it looks like you won't know what size to give it until later in the program, you might want to look into dynamic allocation (using [`malloc(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and [`free(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free)) or possibly a [variable-length array](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), if you can use C99 features.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to debug because your code doesn't even compile. It doesn't compile because you're declaring `Img` as an array of pointers to `gray` but without specifying a size. Thus the compiler doesn't know how big the array is supposed to be and complains.